# Increase SOAP API call limit

Tags: soap-api, bulkification

Is there any workaround in order to fetch more that 200 records at a time when executing a SOQL query? I have 1400+ rows that needs to be executed but I am unable to do so as the SOQL limit is getting exceeded because only 200 records get executed at a time.

Comment: From where are you firing the query?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mix up with the total number of SOQL queries issued?

Comment: A method is being called from an After trigger, which is defined in a class. And that class has around 20 SOQL queries that needs to be executed. So, if the queries execute for a batch of 200, then it executes 8 times. Hence, exceeding the governor limits.

Answer (score 3):

In the SOAP api, the number of records returned is controlled by the batchSize header. The maximum value is 2000:

```
<se:Envelope xmlns:se="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <se:Header xmlns:sfns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <sfns:SessionHeader>
        <sessionId><session-id></sessionId>
    </sfns:SessionHeader>
    <sfns:QueryOptions>
        <batchSize>2000</batchSize>
    </sfns:QueryOptions>
    </se:Header>
    <se:Body>
        <query xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns1="sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <queryString><query-string></queryString>
        </query>
    </se:Body>
</se:Envelope>
```

[Change the Batch Size in Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is only a "hint", as salesforce may reduce the size so as not to exceed maximum SOAP payload limits.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing in your comments sounds more like a trigger bulkification problem than anything to do with the SOAP API batch sizes.

> A method is being called from an After trigger, which is defined in a class. And that class has around 20 SOQL queries that needs to be executed. So, if the queries execute for a batch of 200, then it executes 8 times. Hence, exceeding the governor limits. 
>    . - ABC

You need to create your triggers to handle up to 200 records at a time. 
Have a read of [Common Bulk Trigger Idioms](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bulk_idioms.htm) and [Trigger and Bulk Request Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

Comment: The trigger is properly bulkified as per the best practices. The problem is due to the number of records being fetched (more than 1400). So, the before trigger, validation rules, after triggers are being executed more than 7 times. Is there any way so that more than 200 records can be executed using SOQL query at a time?

Comment: @ABC That sounds correct. DML operations are run through in batches of 200. So I'd expect 7 batches for 1400 records.

Comment: Is there any workaround in order to increase this limit?

Comment: @ABC. No, I don't believe so. It is by design that all insert/update/delete transactions occur on 200 records at a time. You could use the Bulk API to do the updates, but the triggers are still going to fire for every 200 records.